# Show a single error message for multiple fields (jQuery validate plugin )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin to validate a form. The fields I validate on the form are `"To", "CC", "Bcc"`.  If two or more of the above mentioned fields has a value and won't pass the validation then I would like to show a single error message `"One or more email addresses are invalid"`.

Pasted below is the working code which shows the error message three times if the input for  `To, Cc, Bcc` is incorrect.

code :

```
App.CreateSendEmailDialogForReports = function (title, reportUrl, from) {

    var dialogOpts = {}
    dialogOpts.autoOpen = false;
    dialogOpts.modal = true;
    dialogOpts.title = 'Send Email';
    dialogOpts.width = 640;
    dialogOpts.draggable = true;
    dialogOpts.resizable = false;
    dialogOpts.show = { effect: 'drop', direction: 'up' };
    dialogOpts.hide = { effect: 'drop', direction: 'up' };
    dialogOpts.close = function (event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
        App.SendEmailReports = undefined;
        $("#dvSendEmail").remove();
        $("#dvReports").append("<div id='dvSendEmail'></div>");
    };
    dialogOpts.open = function (event, ui) {

        //set the focus on the checkbox to avoid focus on the To or Note field as on focus clears the default messages
        document.getElementById('CopyMeBox').focus();

        $.validator.addMethod("multiemail", function (value, element) {
            if (this.optional(element)) // return true on optional element
                return true;

            var emails = value.split(new RegExp("\\s*,\\s*", "gi"));
            valid = true;
            for (var i in emails) {
                value = emails[i];
                value = value.commaTrim().trim();
                if (value.length == 0)
                    continue;
                try {
                    valid = valid && $.validator.methods.email.call(this, value, element);
                } catch (e) {
                    App.log(e.toString());
                }

            }
            return valid;
        }, 'One or more email addresses are invalid');


        $("#frmSendEmail", "#dvSendEmail").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: "#msgBox",
            wrapper: "li",
            onfocusout: false,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var $form = $(form);
                var url = $form.attr('action');
                var tofield, fromfield, notesfield, urlfield, reportNamefield, ccfield, bccfield, subjectfield;
                // get some values from elements on the page:
                tofield = $form.find('#To').val();

                ccfield = $form.find('#Cc').val();
                bccfield = $form.find('#Bcc').val();
                subjectfield = $form.find('#Subject').val() ;

                fromfield = $form.find('#From').val();



                //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   

                $.post(url, { To: tofield, Cc: ccfield, Bcc: bccfield, Subject: subjectfield, From: fromfield },
                    function (data) {
                        var content = document.createElement('h3').appendChild(document.createTextNode('<p>Email with link to <b>' + urlfield + '</b>' + ' was successfully sent!</p>'));
                        $("#frmSendEmail", "#dvSendEmail").empty().append(content.data);
                        setTimeout(function () { App.SendEmailReports.dialog("close"); }, 1000);

                    }
                    );
            },
            rules: {
                'To': {
                    multiemail: true
                },
                 'Cc': {
                    multiemail: true
        },
                 'Bcc': {
                     multiemail: true
                 }
            }

        });

    };

    if (typeof App.SendEmailReports != "undefined") {
        App.SendEmailReports.dialog("open");
    }
    else {
        App.SendEmailReports = $('#dvSendEmail').dialog(dialogOpts);
        App.SendEmailReports.dialog("open");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)... it's for grouping messages from several fields into one...

```
rules: {
    To: {
        multiemail: true
    },
    Cc: {
        multiemail: true
    },
    Bcc: {
        multiemail: true
    }
},
groups: {
    someGroup: "To Cc Bcc"
}
```

From the docs:

> *"Specify grouping of error messages. A group consists of an arbitrary group name as the key and a space separated list of element names as the value. Use `errorPlacement` to control where the group message is placed."*

---

*BTW: Quotes are not required around the field names unless they contain special characters, like dots or brackets, that would break the JavaScript.*

Comment: thank you. Only the "To" is mandatory among the three. With "groups"  all the three fields are higlighted even I entered data into only one of the fields. But I want to highlight that field only which has a wrong entry.

Comment: @BumbleBee, not sure what to tell you.  This option was only designed to group the messages together.  I don't see how it can be "highlighting" an optional field as required.  Can you construct a simple jsFiddle demo?

Comment: @BumbleBee, I'm not seeing what you describe.  Look at this demo where only one field out of two is required and the two messages are grouped into one.  I made the background red on any error.  The optional field is not highlighted red when there is no error on it.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/8FHd2/

Comment: How to make any one of the three (To, Cc, Bcc) is mandatory. (either To or Cc or Bcc).

Comment: @BumbleBee, that's what the `require_from_group` rule is for.  It's part of the `additional-methods.js` file.  Although in your question you said everything was working except for seeing the message duplicated three times.  Quote OP:  _"Pasted below is **the working code** which shows the error message three times"_

Comment: thats right everything is workign fine. The groups: fixed the message duplicates. Now the issue is I have to enforce the rule to induce the user to enter value for at least one of the three fields(To, Cc, Bcc).

Comment: @BumbleBee, if the only issue was message duplicates, then simply adding the `groups` option has absolutely nothing to do with how the rules are enforced... the same exact fields are required with and without the `groups` option.  I gave you a solution and I gave you a jsFiddle showing how that solution works.  Now it's your turn to create a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem you describe.  Otherwise, I have no idea what you're talking about.