# Problems with jquery-validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin to validate a form. The fields I validate on the form are "To", "CC", "Bcc".

I encounter the following strange issues on validation using jquery-validate :

1. jquery-validate won't validate just the second field. It validates the third. ( I interchaged the cc with Bcc Now Bcc is in second place it won't get validated).
2. enter some text in any of the fields and delete the text and hit "Submit" the validation won't work.

I created a JSfiddle with three text fields it seems to be working. [Example JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FHd2/6/)

Pasted below is the code:

```
  App.CreateSendEmailDialogForReports = function (title, reportUrl, from) {


        dialogOpts.open = function (event, ui) {


            $.validator.addMethod("multiemail", function (value, element) {

                var emails = value.split(new RegExp("\\s*,\\s*", "gi"));
                valid = true;
                for (var i in emails) {
                    value = emails[i];
                    value = value.commaTrim().trim();
                    if (value.length == 0)
                        continue;
                    try {
                        valid = valid && $.validator.methods.email.call(this, value, element);
                    } catch (e) {
                        App.log(e.toString());
                    }

                }
                return valid;
            }, 'One or more email addresses are invalid');


            $("#frmSendEmail", "#dvSendEmail").validate({
                  errorLabelContainer: "#msgBox",
            wrapper: "li",
            onfocusout: false,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var $form = $(form);
                //var url = GetPath($form.attr('action'));
                var url = $form.attr('action');
               // var tofield, fromfield, msgfield, urlfield, reportNamefield, ccfield, bccfield, subjectfield;
                var tofield, fromfield, notesfield, urlfield, reportNamefield, ccfield, bccfield, subjectfield;
                // get some values from elements on the page:
                tofield = $form.find('#To').val();

                ccfield = $form.find('#Cc').val();
                bccfield = $form.find('#Bcc').val();

                subjectfield = $form.find('#Subject').val() ;

                fromfield = $form.find('#From').val();

                //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   

                $.post(url, { To: tofield, Cc: ccfield, Bcc: bccfield, Subject: subjectfield, From: fromfield },
                    function (data) {
                        var content = document.createElement('h3').appendChild(document.createTextNode('<p>Email with link to <b>' + urlfield + '</b>' + ' was successfully sent!</p>'));
                        $("#frmSendEmail", "#dvSendEmail").empty().append(content.data);
                        setTimeout(function () { App.SendEmailReports.dialog("close"); }, 1000);


                    }
                    );
            },          
                rules: {
                "To": {                    
                    require_from_group: [1, ".reqrd"],
                    multiemail: true
                    },
                 "Cc": {
                     require_from_group: [1, ".reqrd"],
                     multiemail: true
        },
                 "Bcc": {
                     require_from_group: [1, ".reqrd"],
                     multiemail: true
                 }
            },

            groups: {
                emailGroup: "To Cc Bcc"
            }

            });

        };

    }
```

Comment: One issue there is that if your jQuery selector matches more than one form, the method will only be applied to the first match.  The solution for that is to use a jQuery `.each()`.

Comment: I checked there is only form with the name "frmSendEmail"

Comment: The problem is in require_from_group.

Comment: Yes, there is a known issue with the `require_from_group` method.  See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22674852/594235

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Validate - require\_from\_group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674611/jquery-validate-require-from-group)

Comment: But FYI - it's only an issue with the error messages, not the validation of the field (form won't submit).  However, since [you wanted to combine all error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647506/show-a-single-error-message-for-multiple-fields-jquery-validate-plugin), then this would be a moot issue.